# Twaindotnet vb Example - Scan immediately after form is loaded

Tags: vb.net, twain

I am trying to use the TwainDotNet package to create a small executable that starts up, sets some parameters, scans the document, saves the image and exits immediately.

I have modeled my app off of the testvb project that is included.

What I have works well if I click on the scan button I left on the form. But if I try to run `scan_click` programatically, the call to `twain.StartScanning(settings)` exits without scanning.

I tried using a timer that triggers a couple of secs after the form is loaded:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Scan_Click(Scan, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

If I click on the Scan button the scanner kicks off correctly. I must be missing something obvious but would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: For a specific answer I would ask a more specific question, or reword your question to be more clear as to what exactly you are asking.

Comment: I was having trouble wording it correctly. In the TwainDotNet TextVB example, if I Click on the Scan button manually the scanner works as expected, if I call the Scan_Click event handler directly , the scanner doesn't doesn't scan

Comment: Was Scan_Click() triggered successfully? You may put an alert in the method to verify that.